# java yahtzee game check for full house

Tags: java

i am making java yahtzee game and I was just wondering if the following code would produce a false positive in any case

die is an array containing pseudo-random(Math.random()) numbers for each die and i have sorted them using a bubble sort
ex:
if randomly thrown die where {1,2,1,2,1) they would then be sorted to {1,1,1,2,2} before being checked by the following code which is inside a method that returns a boolean value.

```
int count = 0;
if(die[0] == die[1] && die[1] == die[2] || die[0] == die[1] && die[2] != die[1]){
    count++;
}
    if(die[3] == die[4]){
        count++;
    }
    if(count > 1){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

Comment: Sort will make it easy to check all kinds of checks. 5 dice have no practical complexity problem, but use insertion sort instead. After the sort, just loop and count repetitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more complicated than it needs to be to sort and then test. It's also slower. Try this, to count how many occurrences of each number, and check that you've got a 3 and a 2. You don't need to sort the array first.

```
int[] counts = new int[6];
for (int i=0; i<die.length; i++)
    //increase the relevant counter
    counts[die[i]-1]++;
//now check we've got a 2 and a 3
boolean check2 = false;
boolean check3 = false;
for (int i: counts) {
    check2 |= (i==2); //found 2 of some number
    check3 |= (i==3); //found 3 of some number
}
return (check2 && check3);
```

Note that this will return `false` for a Yahtzee where all five are the same. It would be easy enough to add a `check5` to allow for this if you want that to return `true`. (Really it ought to return `true`, since it's allowable to count a Yahtzee as a full house if you want to.) It would then become:

```
int[] counts = new int[6];
for (int i=0; i<die.length; i++)
    //increase the relevant counter
    counts[die[i]-1]++;
//now check we've got a 2 and a 3
boolean check2 = false;
boolean check3 = false;
for (int i: counts) {
    check2 |= (i==2); //found 2 of some number
    check3 |= (i==3); //found 3 of some number
    if (i==5) return true; //found a Yahtzee so stop and return true
}
return (check2 && check3);
```

By the way, you really shouldn't ever use bubble sort for anything at all, even if you won't notice its inefficiencies with an array with only five elements in it...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the correctness of your code i would recommend Unit Tests (eg. with Junit). 
Try to test as many cases as possible, using Parameterized Tests might help. 
See: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/junit/junit-parameterized-test-example/

Answer (score 0):

You would check how many numbers are there, so your base algo is like this then:

```
int[] amount = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }

for(int i = 0; i < dices.length; i++ ) { // dices is your integer array
   switch( dices[i] ) {
      case 1: amount[1] += 1; break;
      // all other cases up to 6
    }
 }

 // from the amount array you can check for other things too, here it is for the full house:
 boolean got3same = false;
 boolean got2same = false;
 for(int i = 0; i < amount.ength && (!got3same || !got2same); i++) {
       if(!got3same && amount[i] == 3) {
          got3same = true; 
       } else if(!got2same && amount[i] == 2) {
          got2same = true;
       }
  }

  if(got3same && got2same) {
      System.out.println("Full House!");
  }
```

Comment: The right idea, but there are lots of things that could be improved: you don't need to initialize an array with zeros; you don't need the `switch` statement but can just use `amount[dices[i]-1]++`; it'll be quicker not to check every time for `(!got3same || !got2same)`.